# Sending Json from Android to Spring Controller

Tags: android, json, spring

I have a problem when I'm trying to send JSONObject from Android App to Spring Controller. I mean on the Client side I'm writing a user data to JSONObject and want to send it in POST method. It's working as I expected but bracket characters (eg. `"{"` ) and others like quotations signs are converted into other characters.

JSONObject:

`{"name":"john","surname":"smith","email":"email@email.com","password":"123"}`

is converted to:

```
"%7B%22name%22%3A%22john%22%2C%22surname%22%3A%22smith%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22email%40email.com%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22123%22%7D="
```

I tried to find a solution but ye, now I'm here.
Below my code from android and controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String registerUserAccount(@RequestBody String userJson) {
    System.out.println(userJson);
    return userJson;
}
```

and the Android part:

```
    public class RegisterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private URL url;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            url = new URL(ServerProperties.REGISTER_URL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(ServerProperties.CONNECT_AND_READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setReadTimeout(ServerProperties.CONNECT_AND_READ_TIMEOUT);

            JSONObject jsonObject = JSONHelper.createRegisterJsonObject(name, surname, email, password);

            System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());

            OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            bufferedWriter.write(jsonObject.toString());

            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                Intent loggedScreenIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(loggedScreenIntent);

                return ServerHelper.getResponseMessage(conn.getInputStream());

            } else {
                System.out.println(ServerMessages.FALSE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE + responseCode);
                return ServerMessages.FALSE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE + responseCode;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ServerMessages.EXCEPTION_MESSAGE + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Sorry for my English and Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Spring for android has resttemplate

Comment: try 'jsonObject.put()' to add your values to the json object

Comment: yep, createRegisterJsonObject method is doing that, but RestTemplate is looking good. I will try to use that.